Android Data Binding - Cannot Access Generated Binding Class for Some Fragments
I'm using Data Binding in my Android project, and I've completed all the necessary setup. However, while I can access the generated binding classes (e.g., FragmentTemplateBinding) for some fragments, I cannot access the binding classes for others.
I’ve tried so far to resolve the issue:
Verified that Data Binding is correctly set up.
Tried Invalidate Caches and Restart in Android Studio.
Ensured that Data Binding is enabled in build.gradle.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project (Clean Project and Rebuild Project).
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.MyViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- UI elements -->
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>



android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}



You don't have any layout named fragment_template, for this PreviewFragment screen, you might try FragmentPreviewBinding which will works, or you might want to create a layout named fragment_template to use it as FragmentTemplateBinding

I actually deleted the TemplateFragment and renamed it PreviewFragment instead

val binding = FragmentPreviewBinding.inflate()  still doesnt work

If viewbinding not working for any files then try configuring viewBinding via buildFeatures. like android -> buildFeatures -> viewBinding = true in build gradle

thanks! . now its working but should i use both in same project?

No, this is fine. I will post it as answer

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You should have viewBinding inside buildFeature which nested inside android.
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}


For more detail you can visit this Official documentation link
